# what is the error in this sql trigger code?

Tags: sql, triggers

```
create trigger stud_marks
```

before INSERT
on
Student
for each row
set Student.total = student.sub1 + student.sub2 ;

Comment: Please tag your DBMS. Why to use a trigger for that? Calculating totals is no task for a trigger, but for the application which will create this insert command. Checking whether the total matches the sum of sub1 and sub2 can be done using a check constraint.

Comment: postgresql. it gives me following error: syntax error at or near "set"
LINE 6: set Student.total = student.sub1 + student.sub2 ;

Answer (score 0):

You can not update in the same table in which you are inserting the record using the trigger.